# "To start" or "to begin" while referring to work or studies times?

Tags: word-choice

What's the correct or acceptable option to refer to the time or work times from the following options?

> 1)  "In which hour do you **begin** / **start** to work tomorrow"?

(it's not his first day at work, I'm just asking him about the time that he's going to **START** or to **BEGIN** tomorrow there.)

> 2) "In which time are you going to **begin** / **start** the university (or
>   studies) tomorrow.

(As well as example NO.1, it's not his first day at the university, I'm just asking him about the time that he's going to **START** or to **BEGIN** tomorrow there.)

Comment: I didn't find the answer to my question in what was called duplicate. I'm focusing on a specific case: work and study times.

Comment: You can use either 'begin' or 'start'. They mean the same thing. You should, however, use "At which hour/time...", not "In which hour/time...". Alternatively, just use "when".

Comment: Thank you. So in bottom line you're saying that both of them in expended use?

Comment: Both are good. You really need an expert to explain finer shades of meaning and usage (if there are any).